# Cannot set custom XML Deserializer on ApiController

Tags: c#, xml, binding, asp.net-mvc-4, xmlserializer

I have a model class which I'm trying to deserialise from XML. The class is decorated with C# attributes:

```
public class Model
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public DateTime time_log { get; set; }
}
```

I have an ApiController with action:

```
public void Post(Model m)
{
    // m.time_log has correct value.
    // m.id always gets default value of 0.
}
```

And providing the following input:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<asset id="100">
  <time_log>30 July 2012</time_log>
</asset>
```

What happens (inside the `Post()` action) is that `m.time_log` is bound to the correct `DateTime` value, but `id` gets its default value of 0.

It seems that the MVC API platform doesn't use XmlSerializer to bind the `m` parameter..., so it doesn't deserialize in the way I expect, which would be fine, but I cannot seem to work out a way to tell it to do so.

So far I have tried (in Global.asax.cs#Application_Start):

1. `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SetSerializer<Asset>(new XmlSerializer(typeof(Asset)));`
2. `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Insert(0, new XmlFormatter());`
3. `ModelBinderProviders.BinderProviders.Add(new XmlModelBinderProvider());`

...where `XmlFormatter` and `XmlModelBindingProvider` are custom implementations which use `XmlSerializer` to deserialize the request body.

Am I missing something really obvious here? How do I force ApiController to let me specify my own way of deserialising the XML?